# Which rules are required in AWS security group of the instance where we need run docker container?

Tags: aws-security-group

If one have to install docker, docker-compose, kubectl in an AWS ubuntu instance then which inbound rules should add in the security group of the instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SSHing into the server, you will be needing TCP port 22 open for your public/private IP. If you are accessing the server over Internet, and your public IP changes as per ISP, you can allow 0.0.0.0/0 for TCP port 22 in the ingress rule for the security group.

Further, for installing packages inside the server, you need to have Internet connectivity from the server itself, therefore, you need to have TCP ports opened for Internet in the egress rules of the security group, mostly you will be needed to allow TCP port 443 for HTTPS connection (or TCP port 80 for HTTP, however depends on how/from where you are installing the packages).